# How do you print the view name on a "view page"?

Tags: views, 7

I have set up a custom template for my new view and need to print the views title at the top of the page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Cant you just set the title in the view?

Answer (score 1):

This should normally just work. What do you mean by "custom template", did you make a .tpl.php file? What .tpl.php did you use?

Comment: Thanks...I made a node--faq.tpl.php (faq being the name of the view) . The view list teasers of a content type called "faq". The teaser titles appear fine, but I'd like to get the views title "faq" at the top of the page. Any pointers most appreciated :)

Comment: Found a work around - added a header to the view (under page settings) and typed page title in the Global text area